# Jboss, spring and intelliJ idea. 404 error

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, jboss

I already try many tutorials and examples, but have one issue with all them.
Every of them show me 404 error after deploy. I think, that problem provided by some property or server.
I use tomcat and JBoss, doesn't matter, this error so stable.
How to configurate all this for stable work?

web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

serer-conext.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.seostella.controller" />



</beans:beans>

URL: http://localhost:8080/test/spring-controller/web-inf/views/ - error
     http://localhost:8080/spring-controller/web-inf/views/ - error
     http://localhost:8080/test/
 and other variations. Project name - spring-controller, JBoss deployed on "localhost:8080/test"
```

project link - http://www.seostella.com/media/post/spring/controller/spring-controller.zip

Comment: So, when you enter an unknown URL, for a web application deployed under an unknown context path, and containing unknown controllers and views, you get an error with an unknown message, and it produces unknown log statements. How could we help?

Comment: _Post edited, added links and other info._

Comment: Your views are under WEB-INF, but you can never access these directly, only via controllers. What are your controllers mapped to?

Comment: Some other answers give an advice - try directly connect to WEB-INF.
Controllers mapped to this jsp pages. like this "@RequestMapping(value = "/requestparam")"